# ImageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap), but the screen has nothing but a blank

Tags: android, bitmap, imageview

```
// private File file;

// c_img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.c_img);

file = new File(
                Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsoluteFile()
                + "/" + getTime() + ".jpg");
        iImg.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, Uri.fromFile(file));
        startActivityForResult(iImg, 1);

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == 1) {
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getAbsolutePath());
        c_img.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}
```

// getTime() returns the current local time.

// xml is:

```
<ImageView 
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="300dp"
    android:id="@+id/c_img"/>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Did you check if your `onActivityResult()` code is running?

Comment: Uh... I am so careless and I ignore it. @joao2fast4u  thank you!